# Undefined selector with Objective-C runtime - blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to create a function where multiple times I do the same thing. I've deceided to go with a block this time. However after writing following code:

```
- (BOOL)readyForProcessing {
    void (^notDeclaredError)(id) = ^(id missingObject) {
        NSString *missingObjectName = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(missingObject));
        NSString *errorDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You need to provide %@ property", missingObjectName];
        [self configureErrorWithLocalizedDescription:errorDescription];
    };

    if (!self.delegate) notDeclaredError(self.delegate);

    return (self.error == nil);
}
```

I get a warning in the line, where I declare `missingObjectName`.

```
 Undeclared selector 'missingObject'
```

I know it will probably try to make a `NSString` from `missingObject` instead of `delegate`. How to pass it this way, that the output will be `delegate` and the code will be inside the block?

Comment: it is warning you that there is no method `-(void) missingObject` in the current class.  What are you actually trying to achieve with this line?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to write `if (!self.delegate) notDeclaredError(@"self.delegate");` - simply pass the string directly to the block.
`

Comment: I'm trying to pull property name to string. I know there is such method, I wrote it in the end of question. I want to know how to pull the name of the property instead of this missingObject ivar.

Comment: It's not dynamic enough. Later there will be a lot of refactor as this method will not be used for 1 property. Changing the name would cause everything to be invalid. Better would be to pass result of `NSStringFromSelector` as argument, but I'm wondering how to do it inside the block.

Comment: if self.delegate is `nil` then you will be actually executing `notDeclaredError(nil)` as `self.delegate` will be evaluated at run time before being passed to the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
- (BOOL)readyForProcessing {
    void (^notDeclaredError)(SEL) = ^(SEL missingObject) {
        NSString *missingObjectName = NSStringFromSelector(missingObject);
        NSString *errorDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You need to provide %@ property", missingObjectName];
        [self configureErrorWithLocalizedDescription:errorDescription];
    };

    if (!self.delegate) notDeclaredError(@selector(delegate));

    return self.error ? NO : YES;
}
```

Comment: Lol, yea, fact ^^. Thanks, will accept in 6minutes as SOF allows.

Comment: Just one note: please fix typo `void (^notDeclaredError)(id)` to `void (^notDeclaredError)(SEL)`